# Disable internet access of another installed android app in device from my app

Tags: android, connection, root

I have created an Android app, in that ***I want to disable internet access of another installed apps*** in device from my app.

Is it possible?

Comment: You added the `root` tag there. Does that mean that the app will always run on a rooted phone?

Comment: Yes @verybadalloc, and is it possible in non-root phone?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this thread from the Android Stackexchange: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40924/block-apps-from-accessing-the-internet-on-android-device.

Many methods are suggested there, with some that might work for non-rooted phones

Comment: Let me check. Thanks!